# How to verify another document reference when creating a new document in Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently setting up a Firestore database containing users and blogposts. Every blogpost has a reference to the user that created it.

I want to use security rules to make sure that only the current authenticated user is able to create, update and delete the blogposts written by him.

The following security rule enables this functionality for **updates** and **deletes**:

```
allow write: if resource.data.user == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
```

However, this is not a viable security rule for **creates** because the resource-object does not exist at the time of creation. It will therefore give me a null-pointer.

I've tried using the request.resource.data.user in its place, as it should be the equivalent of resource.data.user, but for the document that *will* be created:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.user == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
```

Unfortunately, this rule simply returns disallows all creates without informing me as to what went wrong.

Does anyone know how to make a security rule with the same functionality as the 1st code-snippet, but which works when attached to **creates**?

EDIT:

Both my 'users' and 'posts' collections are root-level collections. Each 'post' has a field called 'user', which is of type *reference*.

If I could extract the 'uid'-part of the 'user'-field and compare it to the logged in user's uid, that would solve the problem.

It would also be fine if I knew how to compare the entire 'user'-field with a document in another collection. That is what I've been trying to do so far without success.

SOLVED:

Apparently

```
allow create: request.resource.data.author.path == /users/$(request.auth.uid);
```

is the **create** equivalent of

```
allow write: if resource.data.user == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
```

It took at lot of trial and error and the logic behind it is lost to me.

Comment: Can you post your database structure. And where you intend to post new blogposts within that structure

Answer (score 2):

Your rules are syntactically and semantically wrong, which probably explains why they fail.

First off, you can't just include a path to a document in the rule. If you want to read that document, you need to call it with `get()`; and if you want to check whether it exists, you need to call it with `exists()`.

For example: say that you only want user to create posts if there is a user profile document for them, you can do so with:

```
allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
```

But in your case, it seems like you're trying to compare the UID of the user making the request with the user profile document. The problem with your current rules is that you're trying to compare the request's UID with the entire user profile document, which will never work. You can only compare values, so you must compare it with *a field inside* the profile document.

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.user == 
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.uid;
```

For another example, see [Access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish in the end is to confirm that the 'user'-field in the newly created 'blogpost'-document corresponds to the user that has been logged in.

In the code-snippets I provided, only the second one fails. The first one works as intended (as far as I can see).

The last code-snippet you provided did not work for me, but I'd assume that it's because there's no uid-field on my user-documents.

Comment: To validate that the document contains the UID of the signed in user, you don't need to access a profile. Just check the request's UID against the resource's UID: `request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid`. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: I have tried that before, but it simply returns disallows the create. I suppose it is because 'request.resource.data.user' is a reference-type while 'request.auth.uid' is a string.

Comment: What do you mean "a reference type"? There is no supported type for storing a reference to a user in a document, so all you can store is their properties. The above rule assumes you store their UID, which is a string.

Comment: Ahh, I see how I might have caused some confusion there. It isn't a reference to the user.auth, but for a document in the root-level collection called 'users'. Each authenticated user has a document in this 'users'-collection. And while I could probably store the uid as a field in each of these 'user'-documents, this seems like a task that should be possible without needing to store extra data.

Comment: The first rule in my answer shows how to check if a document with the UID as its name exists.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't check whether that document is the same as the one that is linked to in the user-field of the post-document that I'm trying to create.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you have: the `user` field in your blogpost document is a reference to a `users` document. A screenshot of the data structure would've gone a long way here btw. I don't think security rules can check for document identity, so you'll have to check values against each other.

Comment: I apologize for that. I didn't realize that that this was the cause of the misunderstanding. So I take it that the conclusion is that I can only achieve this by putting comparable values on my documents. It does seem like a very common use-case, which is why I've been a bit steadfast in trying to find a better approach.